# Unable to enter new command in ubuntu terminal/ ssh permission denied

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, permission-denied, ubuntu-16.04, master-slave

I was trying to sync the master and slave by following a youtube video when I encountered the permission denied issue while trying to resolve it 'i got stuck with `>`, now I cant enter any new command. Please guide me how can I goto a new line to enter new commands and get rid of the permission error. 
I'm a linux/aws newbee. I appreciate your suggestions.

[image: Below is my terminal:]
No matter what i do i'm stuck with ">". How can I enter a new command?

Answer (score 2):

Note the `>` in the start of the line. This means you don't have a prompt (`$`), but you are still editing the first line from the prompt.

If you look closely, you will also notice the ``` `` ``` on the line with prompt, which starts a sub-command and the shell waits for the matching `` ` ``.

You would do the best with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, which will cancel the current line and you can try again.

Comment: ctrl + c worked but the the connection got disconnected "hduser@ip-172-31-18-212:~/.ssh$ packet_write_wait: Connection to 54.189.237.84 port 22: Broken pipe"

Comment: The disconnect was because of your inactivit. You were waiting 10 hours.

Comment: I realized that. Thankyou @Jakuje.

Comment: can you please take a look at

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40057042/unable-to-upload-directory-to-hdfs-usr-local-tmp-no-such-file-or-directory