# Unable to upload directory to hdfs. `/usr/local/tmp/': No such file or directory

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, amazon-ec2, hdfs, master-slave

I'm trying to upload files in directory to a directory i made on HDFS but I'm not able to do so as ubuntu is not able to locate the files on my machine.
The directory 'states'(one i'm trying to upload) contains 50 txt files, is in my download folder(path: /home/shradha/Downloads). I'm trying to upload these files in my ec2 hadoop instance in hdfs/states (i have already created hdfs and states).
I read somewhere that only files in 'tmp' folder can be moved so i moved the directory i want to upload to hdfs to tmp folder still no luck.
I've tries put, copyFromLocal, moveFromLocal but nothing has worked. Please take a look at the screen shot, I believe it has something to do with the hduser.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: fyi: I'm suppose to have 4 instances executing map-reduce on these 50 files. The terminal in this screen shot is my master node.
If possible can you please suggest where should i place my jar(containing the map-reduce java code) on hadoop? I'm assuming I'll have to use similar command(like input files) to upload it.

Comment: 1) do not post the terminal output as an image. It is not indexable, copyable and nothing. 2) Can you list the files? Are they on that machine or on some other?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu on virtual box. The files i want to upload are present in folder states, which is present here: '/home/shradha/Downloads'.  the folder states has 50 text files which I want to upload to hdfs.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting says the files you want to copy does not exist.
Try to move ONE file and see what are the result.

use `namei -mo <file>` to see the user and the permissions over the file and parents folders.

I.E:

```
[hduser@hdp-clt wordcount]$ namei -mo output/combiner/part-00000 
f: output/combiner/part-00000
 drwxr-xr-x hduser common output
 drwxr-xr-x hduser common combiner
 -rw-r--r-- hduser common part-00000
```

This will help you to understand what's wrong.

Comment: Itriednamei -mo /home/shradha/Downloads/states
f: /home/shradha/Downloads/states
 drwxr-xr-x root root /
 drwxr-xr-x root root home
                      shradha - No such file or directory

Comment: I tried 'namei -mo /home/shradha/Downloads/states f: /home/shradha/Downloads/states' drwxr-xr-x root root / drwxr-xr-x root root home shradha - No such file or directory

Comment: I'm using virtual box, the folder to be uploaded is in my Downloads folder of the Ubuntu Virtual Box I'm using. /home/shradha/Download is the property it shows when I right click on the folder.

Comment: You did not moved a single file as I asked to you, check if you have free space on the disk where the files are and as final option you can use `sudo namei -mo /home/shradha/Downloads/states` to see what is happening at kernel level.